# Pandas Outerjoin New Rows

Tags: pandas, merge, outer-join

I have two dataframes `df1` and `df2`.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({ 
    'Col1': ['abc', 'qrt', 'xyz', 'xam', 'asc', 'yat'], 
    'Col2': ['Revenues','EBT', 'Expenses', 'Revenues', 'EBT', 'Expenses'],
    'Col3': [100, 120, 130, 200, 190, 210],})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({ 
    'Col1': ['abc', 'qrt', 'xyz', 'mas', 'apc', 'ywt'], 
    'Col2': ['Revenues','EBT', 'Expenses', 'Revenues', 'EBT', 'Expenses'],
    'Col4': [120, 140, 120, 200, 190, 210],})
```

I do an outerjoin on the two dataframes:

```
df = pd.merge(df1, df2[['Col1', 'Col4']], on= 'Col1', how='outer')
```

I get a new dataframe but I don't get the entries for `Col2` for `df2`. I get

```
df = pd.DataFrame({ 
    'Col1': ['abc', 'qrt', 'xyz', 'xam', 'asc', 'yat', 'mas', 'apc', 'ywt'], 
    'Col2': ['Revenues','EBT', 'Expenses', 'Revenues', 'EBT', 'Expenses', 'NaN', 'NaN', 'NaN'],
    'Col3': [100, 120, 130, 200, 190, 210, 'NaN', 'NaN', 'NaN'],
    'Col4': [120, 140, 120, 'NaN', 'NaN', 'NaN', '200', '190', '210']})
```

But what I want is:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({ 
    'Col1': ['abc', 'qrt', 'xyz', 'xam', 'asc', 'yat', 'mas', 'apc', 'ywt'], 
    'Col2': ['Revenues','EBT', 'Expenses', 'Revenues', 'EBT', 'Expenses', 'Revenues', 'EBT', 'Expenses'],
    'Col3': [100, 120, 130, 200, 190, 210, 'NaN', 'NaN', 'NaN'],
    'Col4': [120, 140, 120, 'NaN', 'NaN', 'NaN', '200', '190', '210']})
```

I want to have the entries for Col2 from df2 as new rows in the merged dataframe

Comment: `pd.merge(df1, df2[['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col4']], on=['Col1', 'Col2'], how='outer')` ?

Comment: df1.merge(df2, how='outer') ??